# Is Hufflepuff's Cup stored in Bellatrix's personal vault or family vault?

Tags: harry-potter, horcrux

The HP Wikia claims that the vault [Helga Hufflepuff's Cup](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Helga_Hufflepuff%27s_Cup) was in was the [Lestrange family vault](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Lestrange_Vault). However, Hermione (under polyjuice as Bellatrix) tells the goblins: "I wish to enter **my** vault." *(emphasis mine)*

Is Hermione asking for Bellatrix's personal vault or the Lestrange family vault?

Comment: Apparently, it's encouraged to ask and answer your own questions around here. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/ This is something I was wondering about and a little bit of research cleared it up for me. Here's hoping posting this here makes it easier for someone else.

Comment: According to common wisdom, considering family assets "mine" isn't really something unexpected for a wife :) Although, given that Rodolfus had a brother who would have a claim on a "family" vault, the question is actually surprisingly interesting.

Answer (score 5):

It is the Lestrange family vault. As Bogrod is taking them to the cart, a goblin interrupts him.

> "We have instructions," he said with a bow to Hermione. "Forgive me,
>   madam, but there have been special orders regarding the vault of
>   Lestrange."
>
> He whispered urgently in Bogrod's ear, but the Imperiused goblin shook
>   him off.
>
> "I am aware of the instructions. Madam Lestrange wishes to visit her
>   vault... Very old family... old clients... This way, please..."